Pandas, How can I group column 1 by column 2 with column 1's absolute max values without changing column 1 to absolute values?
So lets say I got a df_1 like this:
    Floor  UV
1   1      -2
2   1      3
3   1      -5
4   1      4
5   2      14
6   2      -15

And I have written this code:
output_df = df_1.loc[df_1.groupby("Floor")["UV"].idxmax()]

Above code gives me:
    Floor  UV
1   1      3
2   2      14

And I want out put to be:
    Floor  UV
1   1      -5
2   2      -15


out = df_1.loc[df_1['UV'].abs().groupby(df_1['Floor']).idxmax()]


Similar thought: df_1.loc[df_1.assign(UV=df_1.UV.abs()).groupby("Floor")["UV"].idxmax()]
